# Auto Scaling and Tick Interval Charting

Tags: c#, algorithm, math, charts

I have a chart that plots data but the charting component picks obscure numbers for the scale and tick interval. I'm trying to define a simple algorithm to do this. The chart will be plotted horizontal with 0 in the middle and two bars one extending left and the other right. For example lets say the values to plot are -60 and 75. I would show something like below (apologies for the crudeness)

-80  -60  -40 -20  0  20  40  60  80

```
     <--------|--------->
```

So I need a way to round up the biggest number to the nearest 10, 100, 1000 etc and a way to decide the tick interval. In order for 0 to be visible the tick interval must divide into the rounded number with no remainder.

Here is what I have so far. I know there is probably a much easier mathematically "pure" method to do this.

```
        //Find the max number rounded
        double factor = 10d;

        if (maxValue >= 1000)
            factor = 1000d;
        else if (maxValue >= 100)
            factor = 100d;

        var roundedMax = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor((maxValue.GetValueOrDefault() + factor) / factor) * factor);

        if (roundedMax == 70 || roundedMax == 90)
            roundedMax += 10;
        else if (roundedMax == 700 || roundedMax == 900)
            roundedMax += 100;

        ViewModel.MaximumValue = roundedMax;
        ViewModel.MinimumValue = roundedMax * -1;

        //Work out the interval for tick marks
        int interval;
        var roundedMax = Convert.ToInt32(ViewModel.MaximumValue);

        if (roundedMax <= 10)
            interval = 2;
        else if (roundedMax <= 20)
            interval = 5;
        else if (roundedMax <= 50)
            interval = 10;
        else if (roundedMax < 100)
            interval = 20;
        else if (roundedMax == 100)
            interval = 25;
        else if (roundedMax <= 200)
            interval = 50;
        else if (roundedMax <= 500)
            interval = 100;
        else if (roundedMax < 1000)
            interval = 200;
        else if (roundedMax == 1000)
            interval = 250;
        else if (roundedMax <= 2000)
            interval = 500;
        else
            interval = 1000;

        ViewModel.TickInterval = interval;
```

Answer (score 2):

(Not knowing anything about C#), I think the general approach might be as follows.

First, determine the power of 10 that is close to your `maxValue`. This can be done taking the base-10 logarithm, something like this (pseudocode)

```
logMax = floor(log10(maxValue))
```

Raise 10 back to this power to get the maximal power of 10 that is smaller than `maxValue`:

```
base = pow(10, logMax)
```

Now you want to find the minimal multiply of `base` that exceeds your `maxValue`:

```
roundedMax = ceil(maxValue / base) * base
```

You can then do some manual correction of `roundedMax` if you want to avoid particular values such as 70 or 90 in your example.

Now you have rounded maximal value. You can round minimal value the same way, or better calculate the `base`s for max and min separately and take maximal of `base`, then round both with respect to the same `base`.

After this you can assign ticks. You can think of many algorithms, most of which will anyway require some manual coding. Basic approach might be as follows: assume you want to have roughly 10 marks. Thus the 'ideal' tick distance will be

```
idealTick = (roundedMax - roundedMin)/10
```

Now you can round `idealTick` to the nearest power of 10 using the same approach:

```
idealTick = pow10(ceil(log10(idealTick)))
```

(I take `ceil` to make sure it is <=10 ticks), now `idealTick` is a power of 10.

You can now fine-tune it to allow for 2*power-of-10 or 5*power-of-ten steps:

```
if (roundedMax-roundedMin)/idealTick <= 2
    idealTick *= 5
else if (roundedMax-roundedMin)/idealTick <= 5
    idealTick *= 2
```

I hope the ideas are clear. I did not test the code, and you might want to fine-tune it more.

Comment: Thanks Petr. I went with a slightly different solution but used many of these ideas.